# What is the Default JDBC Character Encoding

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, coldfusion, character-encoding

I'm developing a Coldfusion app and have seen that I can't insert certain characters into the database. I believe that I can change the JDBC connection string to enable unicode encoding.

However, I would like to know what the default encoding that JDBC uses so I can say what character set is currently safe to use. I can't seem to find information on what the default is anywhere. Does anyone know the default?

Edit:

What it is, while the database is all set for unicode (i can directly insert unicode characters with no problem with SQl using my MySQL client), if i try to insert data from Coldfusion it seems it can't handle the unicode chracters, so it seems the default connection string it uses (we're not specifying one yet) is not unicode compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL default encoding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html) is latin1

> For applications that store data using the default MySQL character set and collation (latin1, latin1_swedish_ci)

Comment: This was it - I ran SHOW VARIABLES through Coldfusion and it showed the character_set_connection and character_set_client as latin1

Answer (score 0):

My notes for ColdFusion say

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">

<cffile
action="read"
file="#settings.csvfile#"
variable="autodata"
charset="utf-8">
```

Meanwhile, establish `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` on any columns that need it.

(It seems folly to stick with the very limited `latin1`, when the future is clearly `UTF-8`.)

Comment: Is the downvote because it is "wrong"?  Or "not helpful"?  Or what?

Comment: I think your answer is good. It covers the specific problem and it brings up a big picture concern. At the time of this writing, UTF-8 is becoming more and more used, but it is not universal yet.

Comment: What it is, while the database is all set for unicode (i can directly insert unicode characters with no problem using my MySQL client), if i try to insert data from Coldfusion it seems it can't handle the unicode chracters, so it seems the default connection string it uses (we're not specifying one yet) is not unicode compatible

Comment: @dVyper - Show us the CF config, the parameters used when connecting to MySQL, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, a hex dump of some non-ascii characters in CF, hex dump of it after `INSERTing` into the database.  One of those is likely to help ferret out the thing that is messing up Unicode.  (And I hope you mean utf8, not "unicode codepoints".)